# Calculating script memory usages in PHP?

Tags: php, memory

Is it as simple as calling `memory_get_usage()` at the start and end of a script and subtracting the 1st from the second value, to get the total memory used on that script?  If so, how can I convert that value to a more understandable number like kb and mb?

Comment: If you have a Meta Stack Overflow account, it would be nice if you linked them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
function file_size($size)
{
    $filesizename = array(" Bytes", " KB", " MB", " GB", " TB", " PB", " EB", " ZB", " YB");
    return $size ? round($size/pow(1024, ($i = floor(log($size, 1024)))), 2) .$filesizename[$i] : '0 Bytes';
}
```

I normally use this to format file sizes, but you can use it to solve your problem.

Comment: Why are you dividing by 1024 multiple times when you can just use the number in your if sentence? And its really KiB, MiB, GiB and TiB for binary (1024) and for decimal (1000) its kB (note lower k), MB, GB and TB.

Answer (score 3):

You may prefer to just call [memory_get_peak_usage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php) at the end of your script, which will return the highest total allocation during execution. This is more likely to be a useful figure - getting the start and end values doesn't account for memory allocated then deallocated during runtime.

Formatting this into a human readable number can be handled manually (just divide by 1024 then print as Kb), or with a class like [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php).